# Post PutRecords directly to kinesis API without (real) authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-sts

I want to send PutRecords requests from a mobile app directly into AWS Kinesis data stream via https API. I don't want to use API Gateway and I don't want to bundle a secret access key with the app. I expect 1M events per second posted by unauthenticated app users. API requires requests to be signed, what would you suggest is the best way to sign requests in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/kinesis-examples-capturing-page-scrolling.html